# SSIS Package Data Manager "Not a valid account name or password"

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have an SSIS Project (version 16.0) that I am developing in Visual Studio 2019. In one of the packages I have a package level Excel Connection Manager. It works fine when I run it. If I try to add the my user credentials (My user name as it appears in the system variable @[System::UserName] and password) I get the error "Not a valid account name or password"

I am confused because I thought that if I don't specify a UserName and Password that it uses my credentials. If I add those same credentials manually it gives me an error. I need to be able to specify credentials so I can deploy it.

Project Security ProtectionLevel is set to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword

Package Security ProtectionLevel is set to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword

Please help me figure out how to use manually entered credentials with the Connection Manager.