# SSIS Visual Studio Excel Connection Manager Username and Password

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am using Visual Studio to build packages for SQL Server Integration Services. When modifying an  "Excel Connection Manager" I see in the properties that there are "UserName" and "Password" properties. I am not sure what these are used for and I can't find any documentation.

Can someone tell me how to use these properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "UserName" and "Password" properties in the "Excel Connection Manager" are not commonly used with Excel files, and that might be why there's confusion surrounding them. These properties might appear in the Connection Manager because the interface is shared with other connection types that do require authentication (such as connecting to a database).

When connecting to an Excel file, you generally don't need to authenticate with a username and password. However, in some rare cases where the Excel file might be hosted on a secure server or location that requires authentication, these properties could theoretically be used.

For standard Excel file connections on your local machine or accessible network paths, you typically don't need to worry about the "UserName" and "Password" properties. Your connection string would more commonly include the file path and other details like the Excel version.

```xml
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\path\to\your\file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

In this case, the username and password properties would be left blank.

Comment: So the UserName and Password are used as credentials for accessing the excel file's location (on a network for example), not for any password that's internal to the excel file  itself?

Comment: the "UserName" and "Password" properties you see in the "Excel Connection Manager" within SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) would typically be used for accessing a location on a network that requires authentication, rather than for a password that might be internal to the Excel file itself.

Comment: Excel files can be password-protected at the file level, but connecting to a password-protected Excel file through SSIS generally involves different properties and settings.

Comment: If you are trying to connect to an Excel file that is located in a place requiring network credentials, you might need to use these properties. Otherwise, in most common scenarios where the Excel file is on your local machine or a network location without special access restrictions, these "UserName" and "Password" properties would be left blank.

Comment: I have tried entering my own UserName and Password to connect to a network share and it did not work. when I left these fields blank it did work. I even posted a question about it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76769227/ssis-package-data-manager-not-a-valid-account-name-or-password